# Selenium webdriver read taking too long

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm opening a discord channel and busy looping reading messages from it with the below statement to get the elements:

```
List<org.openqa.WebElement> ret = driver.findElement(By.tagName("main")) // driver = WebDriver
            .findElements(By.tagName("li"))
            .stream()
            .filter(message -> message.getAttribute("id") != null
                    && message.getAttribute("id").contains("chat-messages"))
            .toList();
```

There are about 40 messages by default shown on the page, and it takes 5-6 seconds for every read. It is unacceptably long. I read that when there are no matches, findElements has an implicit wait time, but that is not the case here as there are elements returned in every read. Any idea what is causing this delay and how to improve it?

Update: From the first answer I received, I tried

```
List<WebElement> ret = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main//li[contains(@id,'chat-messages')]"));
```

At first it appeared like it was fast but soon I realized it must have been some temporary thing. It is taking just as long as before.

Update: Shamefully upon some debugging I found out that the driver.findElements is not the one taking several seconds, it only takes under 20 millis, but I have some code reading attributes from the remote web element of all of the returned elements, which is what is causing the delay. I have restructured the code now that it only has the read the attributes of the last message returned from findElements, and maintain its timestamp for identifying new messages next time.

Comment: are you sure selenium is the correct tool for the task at hand? perhaps try the [discord java api](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFsxkWME7M0)

Comment: I'm using a non bot account and Discord doesn't allow reading using API for person accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> ret = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main//li[contains(@id,'chat-messages')]"));
```

Rather than retrieving the elements one at a time it helps to let xpath do the work and retrieve them all in one call.

Comment: It helps to explain your answer.

Comment: It is still taking a little over 4 seconds now. Can it be speeded up more?

Answer (score 0):

Try what results and performance you get with `cssSelector`.

Something like this:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("main [id^=chat-message]"));
```

or even without `main`

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^=chat-message]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**PageLoadStrategy:** Have you tried to change the PageLoadStrategy? It might not be slow due to the amount of elements you try to recieve but because Selenium is also waiting for the `Document.readyState`.

[By default the PLS for Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/) is to wait for a page to return `complete`, but a lot of new web applications are asynchronous (AJAX) and already return the right elements while the readyState of the browser is still in `interactive`.

To set the PLS to a mode where it looks for elements already without waiting for `complete`, you need to change the default option. For Chrome it can be done like this:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The most fast way to grab this information is to do this by direct API calls, not to read it from GUI elements at all.
2. More slow, but still more fast than with Selenium is to read this data with `BeautifulSoup`.
3. In case page long loading time is caused by some kinds of scripts on the page you can set [Page Load Strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/capabilities_exports_PageLoadStrategy.html) to `EAGER`, this will significantly reduce this kind of delays.
4. You can use [Headless browser](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-headless-browser-testing/). In this mode Selenium driver performs faster than in regular, visible mode.

Comment: I'm using a non bot account and Discord doesn't allow reading using API for person accounts.

Comment: OK, but there are still 3 additional approaches to do that faster than with regular Selenium...

Answer (score 0):

You said you know about the implicit wait, but did you try to reduce it? I've had a similar problem when finding multiple elements in the past. See [the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) according to your language.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(0.1) // depends on language
List<org.openqa.WebElement> ret = driver.findElement(By.tagName("main")) // driver = WebDriver
            .findElements(By.tagName("li"))
            .stream()
            .filter(message -> message.getAttribute("id") != null
                    && message.getAttribute("id").contains("chat-messages"))
            .toList();
```